# How to access data from the Google's "best match" or "most relevant" feature.

Tags: gwt

I am trying to access data from Google's  "best match" or "most relevant" feature. It looks like this:

[image: The White Box]

I am looking to get the text with the instructions.
I looked around the APIs but I can't seem to find anything. Could anyone tell me as to how I could approach this?